# Photon Cloud Offline Mode Can't find Spawn Points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm following user: quill18creates on youtube multiplayer FPS tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CnKc9k6shQA

I'm having a problem when setting the offline mode to true. When I try to run my application, I get the

```
Debug.Log("No spawn spots!!!");
```

message on the console log. However, when switching back to online mode I can find the spawn points and play as normal? I've attached my code below (can also be seen on youtube video).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Camera standbyCamera;
private SpawnSpot[] spawnSpots;

public bool offlineMode = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Connect ();
    spawnSpots = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SpawnSpot> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void Connect() {
    if (offlineMode) {
        PhotonNetwork.offlineMode = true;
        OnJoinedLobby();
    } else {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ("0.0.0.1");
    }
}

void OnGUI() {
    GUILayout.Label (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString ());
}

void OnJoinedLobby() {
    Debug.Log ("OnJoinedLobby");
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom ();
}

void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed() {
    Debug.Log ("OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed");
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom (null);
}

void OnJoinedRoom() {
    Debug.Log ("OnJoinedRoom");
    SpawnMyPlayer ();

}

void SpawnMyPlayer() {
    Debug.Log ("SpawnMyPlayer");

    if (spawnSpots == null) {
        Debug.Log("No spawn spots!!!");
        return;
    }

    SpawnSpot mySpawnSpot = spawnSpots [Random.Range (0, spawnSpots.Length)];
    GameObject myPlayerGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("Player", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
    myPlayerGO.GetComponent<UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
    myPlayerGO.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().enabled = true;
    myPlayerGO.transform.FindChild ("FirstPersonCharacter").gameObject.SetActive (true);
    standbyCamera.enabled = false;
}
}
```

Comment: According to you code spawnSpots variable initialized with GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SpawnSpot> ();
Unity can't find object of type SpawnSpot in scene at the moment when Start() is called.
It's not clear from code why this object is in the scene only if offlineMode == false

Comment: Why does multiplayer work then?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but I believe the problem is the Connect function, change your Start function to:

```
void Start () {
    spawnPoints = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SpawnPoint>();
    Connect();
}
```

Comment: I've not tried this solution yet although why does this work on multilayer if the two need switched? Also, I can't connect first. If you follow the code it'll try and spawn before any spawnPoints are assigned this way.